# Sound cut out after a few minutes of playing (regardless of media)

Tags: sound

I am running ubuntu 16.04 on a Thinkpad X201. The issue I'm having is that the sound cuts out after a few minutes, regardless of the source of the audio (Rhythmbox, YouTube in either Chromium or Firefox, VLC, or the built in video player). I'm not sure what's going on with the internal audio, and I'm not sure where to begin to diagnose it. The problem seems to go away after reboot, but them comes back.

Sound related issues from dmesg

```
[    3.280231] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    3.280233] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=2 (0x1c/0x19/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    3.280234] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[    3.280235] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
[    3.280237] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0:      Internal Mic=0x23
[    3.280239] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0:      Mic=0x1b
[    3.280240] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0:      Dock Mic=0x1a
[    3.281704] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0: Enable sync_write for stable communication
[    3.338059] input: HDA Intel MID Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input11
[    3.338156] input: HDA Intel MID Dock Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input12
[    3.338277] input: HDA Intel MID Dock Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input13
[    3.338367] input: HDA Intel MID Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input14
[    3.338452] input: HDA Intel MID HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input15
```

Comment: Does the output of `dmesg` show anything audio related?

Comment: So, it produced 22 pages of output. The only thing related to sound I'm posting in the question. There's some errors with and ACPI device, but I don't know if that's related.